# phonegap, javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

```
    xmlStObj.find("Control").each(function(){
            var value = $(this).find("value").text();
            $(this).find("value").text('New Value');    
        });
    }

alert($(xmlStObj));
alert(xmlStObj)
```

both prints Object, Object

How to write value of this object to sqlite db?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xmlStObj.find("Control").each(function(key,val){
        console.log("Key is "+key); 
        console.log("Value(s)");

        console.log(val); 

        //for example if you have key (text)
        console.log(val.text); 

    });
}
```

I hope this what you are looking for and if not I hope it can help